# lyncClient.GetClient() throw exception when set UISuppressionMode as 1

Tags: lync, lync-2010

I'm new for Lync client 2010 SDK integration. Since I don't want to display Lync UI (we will develop our own UIs), I set the registry to make UISuppressionMode = 1(DWORD). But lyncClient.GetClient() throws ClientNotFoundException exception. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could well be that the client isn't actually running, which is why it's not found.

When you're running in UISuppression mode, you're responsible for everything which the client normally does, such as starting up, shutting down, and signing in.

You have to start the Lync client using `LyncClient.BeginInitialize` - you can't just start it from the start menu. You should also call `LyncClient.BeginShutdown` when you're done. (ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh345230%28v=office.14%29.aspx))

There's a good [MSDN article on UI Suppression in Lync SDK here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj933224.aspx), and there's also a [channel9 video on signing into Lync when UISuppresion mode is on](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Sign-In-to-Lync-with-UI-Suppressed).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I found why the client didn't start. My windows8 system has Lync2013 basic installed. For some reason lync 2013 SDK installing failed because it required lyncsdk86.msi that I don't know where to get. So I installed Lync2010 and lync2010 SDK. With Lync2013 lyncClient.GetClient() doesn't work. After I remove Lync2013, it works. It is annoying that Lycn2013 doesn't compatible with Lync 2010.

Comment: Right yes. This should have been sorted - see here: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/07/using-lync-2010-applications-with-lync-2013-and-lync-2013-applications-with-lync-2010/